# Problema al añadir una clase CSS a elementos

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Estoy haciendo un teclado virtual y tengo problemas con la tecla para mayúsculas. Quiero que al pulsar el botón Caps éste se ponga en rojo con una clase y el resto de teclas se pongan en mayúsculas.

Tengo este código pero hay algo que no me funciona:

```
let caps = document.querySelector('.js-caps');
let key = document.querySelectorAll('.js-key');
for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    key[i].addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
}

function handleButtonClick(ev) {
    textarea.innerHTML += ev.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    console.log(ev.currentTarget.innerText)
    console.log(ev.currentTarget.innerText.toUpperCase())
    
}
function handleCapsClick(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    caps.classList.toggle("red");
    if (caps===".red"){
    key.classList.add ("upper");
    }else{
    key.classList.remove ("upper");
    }   
    }
caps.addEventListener('click', handleCapsClick);
```

Comment: El evento "click" hace referencia a los botones del ratón, no a las teclas. Te aconsejo que busques información sobre "keydown" y "keyup"

Comment: Claro, es que es un teclado virtual... al pulsar con el ratón en la tecla escribe la letra del innerhtml. No uso el teclado físico por lo que keydown ni keyup me sirven
Lo que necesito es que si pulso con el ratón en caps el resto de teclas se conviertan en letras mayúsculas

Comment: No había entiendo el escenario, tienes razón. Ya veo el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La llamada a `querySelectorAll` devuelve una lista de objetos:

Tienes

```
let key = document.querySelectorAll('.js-key');
```

Quizá la variable debería llamarse `keys` para evitar confusiones, porque primero la usas correctamente, recorriendo la lista:

```
for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    key[i].addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
}
```

Pero dentro de la función handleCapsClick la tratas como si fuese un único elemento:

```
function handleCapsClick(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  caps.classList.toggle("red");
  if (caps===".red"){
    key.classList.add ("upper");
  }else{
    key.classList.remove ("upper");
  }   
}
```

La solución es sencilla:

```
function handleCapsClick(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  caps.classList.toggle("red");
  key.forEach(elem => elem.classList.toggle("upper"));
}
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Es lo que me lo ha solucionado!!!